# What different between [multi_accept] and [accept_mutex]?

Tags: nginx

`multi_accept`

> If multi_accept is disabled, a worker process will accept one new connection at a time. Otherwise, a worker process will accept all new connections at a time.

`accept_mutex`

> If accept_mutex is enabled, worker processes will accept new connections by turn. Otherwise, all worker processes will be notified about new connections, and if volume of new connections is low, some of the worker processes may just waste system resources.

Definitions from [**docs**](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html) are very similar..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `accept_mutex` controls whether 1 *connection* can wake multiple *workers*, while `multi_accept` controls whether 1 *worker* can accept multiple *connections*.